# After deleting question, how many days are required to ask a question in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, asking-questions, up-votes

I am new to this site, and I have asked some questions. Some questions I got a reply to and some of them no replies at all. For one question I was down-voted to -2.

After that I was getting message like:

> **Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.**

After that I had deleted some unanswered question from my account. After deleting a question how many days arerequired to ask a question?

Still I am getting the same error. What should I do?

How do to up-vote my question and release lock?

Comment: Thanks i red that. if i delete question, am no longer to ask again ?

Comment: Time is not a factor. Question ban can last for a life time. Read the linked dupe again, this time while actually reading it, and you will understand.